# Django extends template tag is written out as text not parsed

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm a beginner trying to learn Django by following tutorials.
I am currently working on template inheritence.

When i try to extend a template.

```
{% extends 'accounts/main.html'}
{% block  content %}
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

The file is not extended. Instead this is written as plain text {% extends 'accounts/main.html'}
when i view the page.

The template i try to extend looks like this.

```
    <!doctype html>

<html lang="sv">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Base template</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

</head>

<body>

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
    

</body>
</html>
```

I have searched for this problem but found no solution.
Can you please help me?

Comment: You forgot a `%` in `%}` (at the end of `{% extends ... %}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First [read Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/)

{% extends ''accounts/main.html' ***%***}  - you miss (%-sign)

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the closing `%` in 1st line.

in my opinion, it's best practice to write the tag first and then enter elements 1 by 1 until you get comfortable with the syntax.

I would start out like this

**`{%  %}`**

and then add

`{%`**`extends`** `%}`

and then
`{% extends`**`'base.html'`** `%}`

Best Wishes.
Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a % at the end

```
{% extends 'accounts/main.html' %}
{% block  content %}
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
{% endblock %}
```